# Is it possible to have multiple public IP addresses for one azure worker role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, nic

I have a azure worker role, displayed as Cloud service (classic). I need to listen on two equal ports on separate IP addresses. Is this possible?

The machine of the worker role would need two nics. In my endpoint configuration of the worker role I would have to configure to which nic the input endpoints belongs to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

With worker/web roles within the same Cloud Service, you can only have a single VIP, mapping to `yourservice.cloudapp.net`. You cannot have mulitple VIPs unless you have a Virtual Machine (either in your classic Cloud Service or modern ARM-based deployment).

This limitation is called out explicitly in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-multivip).

Comment: Could the problem be solved with some kind of routing? The thing is, I need two public endpoints with port 443, which are mapped to a completely different service on my worker role. Is there any way to route port 443 of my second public IP to any other port of my worker role?